# No Instance Error in Haskell Program

Tags: haskell

I wanted to Print to A pascal Triangle for a given Length.

```
main = do 
  l_str <- getLine
  let l_int = read $ l_str :: Int     
  let why = print_row l_int 0
  print why
  return ()

print_row x y
     | (x < y) = " "    
     | otherwise = (print_column y 0 ) ++ "\n" ++ print_row x (y+1) 
print_column y r
     | (y < r) = ""
     | otherwise = (show $ fact y r ) ++ print_column y (r+1)   
fact n r
     |  (n >= r) = truncate $ (fact' n)/((fact' (n-r))*(fact' r))
fact' n
     | (n >= 0) = product [1..n]
```

I have checked all my functions "print_row" ,"print_column" everything works fine.
I am getting this error:

> PascalTriangle.hs:4:17:
>       No instance for (RealFrac Int) arising from a use of ‘fact’
>       In the expression: fact l_int 0
>       In an equation for ‘why’: why = fact l_int 0
>       In the expression:
>         do { l_str <- getLine;
>              let l_int = ...;
>              let why = fact l_int 0;
>              print why;
>              .... }

I am not able Understand anything about this error.The pogram works fine when I use a constant instead of l_int in line 4.Like let why = print_row 4 0.

Comment: A general strategy that often helps with errors like this is to add type signatures to your functions.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you may prefer `readLn` over `read <$> getLine` in the future; on parse errors, the former throws an IO exception right away, instead of a difficult-to-trace pure exception at some ill-defined later point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `div` instead of `/`.

`div` will take two Integral values and return another Integral value - e.g. `div 5 2 == 2`. Then you'll also need to get rid of the `truncate` call.

`/` does "floating point" division.

`fromIntegral` will convert an Integral value to any other `Num` type.

Comment: I want to print the result in different lines so I added "\n" but it is not working.